# Hourly wind speed data extraction from GEE using ERA5_LAND HOURLY image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, climate, copernicus

I am trying to extract hourly wind speed data using 'u_component_of_wind_10m' and 'v_component_of_wind_10m' from ERA5_LAND HOURLY image collection for September 2017 for Dominica.
The .csv file shows daily averaged wind speed in m/s which I do not want.
I want hourly data from 00:00 to 23:59 for each day from September 1st to 1st October 2017. So each day will have wind speed for separate hours. I want to export that in .csv format.

The chart I am getting is averaged for each day, basically I am getting daily wind speed chart.
I want to generate an hourly wind speed chart from 16th September to 18th September 2017.
I am unable to get wind speed in an hourly timestamp.
I am a beginner in GEE.

Here is the code I am trying to modify.

```
      
var ERA5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
     .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-09-01', '2017-10-01'))     

var ERA5DOM=ERA5.map(function(im){ 
   return im.clip(AOI);
});


// Wind calculation
var ERA5windspeed = ERA5DOM.map(function(image){
  var wind_10m = image.expression(
    'sqrt(u**2 + v**2)', {
      'u': image.select('u_component_of_wind_10m'),
      'v': image.select('v_component_of_wind_10m')
  }).rename('windspeed');
  
  var time = image.get('system:time_start');
  return wind_10m.set('system:time_start', time) } );
  
print(ERA5windspeed);

Map.setCenter(-61.34, 15.4, 12);

var vis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 5,
  palette: [
    '#FFFFFF', '#FFFF71', '#DEFF00', '#9EFF00', '#77B038', '#007E55', '#005F51',
    '#004B51', '#013A7B', '#023AAD'
  ]
};

Map.addLayer(ERA5windspeed.select('windspeed'), vis, "Wind speed (m/s) 10m above surface");

var Wind_chart = ui.Chart.image.series(ERA5windspeed, AOI, ee.Reducer.mean(), 1000, 'system:time_start')
  .setOptions({
 title: 'Wind speed Full Time Series',
 vAxis: {title: 'm/s'},  });
print(Wind_chart);
```

At the end I am trying to generate wind speed data and also combne it with wind direction for the whole island of Dominica.

Comment: You only get one measurement per day because, as you explained, you're filtering to only include hour 13 when you call `filterMetadata`. Don't filter by hour if you want to include every hour.

Comment: Yes, but while exporting I am still having daily wind speed data and not hourly.

Comment: Are you exporting the CSV by clicking on the chart and using the "Download CSV" button? If so, the problem is that the chart automatically formats the times to only include the day, so you would have 24 rows for each day but all with the same "system:time_start". If that's the case, you can fix it by adding a new property with a formatted time and using that in the chart. Something like this: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1a1bc8bf9a48e2aeb617bb275a212c67